# Confidence interval for a standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

To build a confidence interval, I have my pivotal quantity say T and the confidence interval is build on $\mathbb{P}(q_{\alpha/2}\leq T\leq q_{1-\alpha/2})=1-\alpha$, where $q_{\alpha/2}$ and $q_{1-\alpha/2}$ are my quantiles of $\alpha/2$ and $1-\alpha/2$ of my pivotal quantity $T$.

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and I obtain $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and I want to build a confidence interval for the mean $\mu$ and suppose $\sigma^2$ is known. I use the empirical mean $\bar{X}$ as my estimator for $\mu$. How come the confidence interval is $\mathbb{P}\left( {\overline{X}-z_{1-\alpha /2}\frac{
\sigma }{\sqrt{n}}\ }\ \leq \mu \leq \ {\overline{X}%
+z_{1-\alpha /2}\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{n}}}\right) =1-\alpha$? Is it because of the symmetric property of the Gaussian that my $z_{\alpha/2}$ becomes $z_{1-\alpha/2}$?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Brian.  We're not really set up to field yes/no questions, no matter how difficult or easy, complicated or simple they might be.   We would have a better understanding of what you are seeking if you would elaborate on your doubt: what makes you think the answer might be anything other than what you propose?

Comment: Dear whuber, many thanks for this message. I am not just sure how I get from the definition $\mathbb{P}(z_{\alpha/2}\leq (\bar{X}-\mu)/(\sigma/\sqrt{n})\leq z_{1-\alpha/2})=1-\alpha$ to expression I wrote

Comment: If for example $\alpha=0.05$.  Then $z_{0.025}\approx -1.96$ and $z_{0.975}\approx +1.96$.  Which one do you want to subtract or add in finding a confidence interval for the mean?

Comment: Hello Henry, thank you for your example, but is it possible to write it down mathematically as $z_{\alpha/2}=-z_{1-\alpha/2}$? If so, how do I prove this?

Comment: You look at a plot of the standard Normal density.  "$z_{\alpha/2} = -z_{1-\alpha/2}$" is one way to state that the graph is its own mirror image around the y-axis.

Comment: Hello whuber, many thanks for this.